# How to convert my own Data constructor to List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-constructor

I have just started trying Haskell after using Python, and I'm facing a lot of problems understanding it

for example after I tried to make a new type called ListBag and writing a simple function to convert list to ListBag I can't go back and do anything with that data:

```
data ListBag a = LB [(a,Int)] deriving (Show,Eq)

fromList :: (Ord a) => [a] ->ListBag a
fromList xs = LB [ y| y<- ys]
            where ys = toList(fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs])

a :: [Integer]
a=[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5]
b = fromList a
```

Now `b` is:

```
LB [(1,6),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(5,2)]
```

and because `b` is `b :: ListBag Integer` it can't be mapped or ...
So how can I convert it to List again?

Comment: `\case{ LB x -> x }`

Comment: `[ y| y<- ys]` is better spelled `ys`. ...and then, given how nondescript that name is, `ys where ys = foo` is probably better spelled `foo`.

Comment: @user2407038 I'm sorry I didn't totally understand, would you please explain more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your `ListBag` doesn't save order in which elements was in initial list, but... you can convert `ListBag a` to `[a]` like so:

```hs
toList :: ListBag a -> [a]
toList (LB ys) = concat $ (\(y, n) -> replicate n y) <$> ys
```

---

And you can redefine your `fromList` as

```hs
fromList xs = LB $ toList $ fromListWith (+) [ (x, 1) | x <- xs]
```

Because `[ y | y <- ys]` ~ `ys` and `x where x = y` ~ `y`

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, monads

```
toList :: ListBag a -> [a]
toList (LB l) = do
  (what, howmany) <- l
  replicate howmany what
```

Or if you like list comprehensions:

```
toList (LB l) =
  [x | (what, howmany) <- l, x <- replicate howmany what]
```

The trick is to make use of the fact that a monadic bind on lists can put arbitrary number of things in place of each element. So for every pair `(what, howmany)` we output `howmany` number of `what`s.

This isn't much different from the SergeyKuz1001's solution, just a different style. Due to optimizations I believe the performance ist rather the same in all versions.

Comment: Existence of people like you, who share their experience with beginners patiently, definitely makes this world a better place... @radrow

Answer (score 2):

@SergeyKuz1001's answer is excellent. When you're ready to take it up a notch, you can use `List`'s Monad instance, and a few combinators to make `toList` very concise.

```hs
toList :: ListBag a -> [a]
toList (LB ys) = ys >>= uncurry (flip replicate)
```